# My transaction was dropped and now when I search the transaction on etherscan it says we are unable to locate this transaction hash. Please help

Tags: web3js

I sent money to a friend with a low fee. After awhile it showed dropped and I was going to replace it with a higher fee but when I tried to open the transaction id to get the nonce it now says its invalid when it worked before when I checked. Now it says has not been returned to me and hasnt been sent out to him. Please help me with this it was a sizeable amount of money the transaction id is `0xacdfaa8ae28a5fc16f50fa6313094083eb2e49ae2593a7909985f8b4bec9c27f`

Answer (score 1):

A transaction may be dropped if it has too low fees or if there's some other error in it: for example invalid nonce.

A dropped transaction means everything is just like the transaction never existed. So you need to reuse the same nonce in your wallet.

As for the assets in the transaction: since the transaction was never executed, no assets left your wallet, and therefore there is no nothing to return. Assets are only deduced from your wallet once a transaction goes through (although different wallets may show this differently).

It is not possible for the assets to be "lost" under any circumstances.